# Bounty on another question

Tags: support, bounty

Am trying to give a bounty in this question [Limiting internet bandwidth for already started applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46545/limiting-internet-bandwidth-for-already-started-applications) but somehow the option does not appeared. I tested on Firefox 4 and Chrome 12/13. It appears in other posts but not that one.

Comment: And you can't add a bounty when another is already running.

Comment: Nice point oxwivi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question must be older than 2 days before you can add a bounty.

For completeness' sake, you also can't add a bounty to a question that has an accepted answer.

See also: [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/favicon.ico How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: i doubt that you can't add a bounty to a question that has an accepted answer.